# How to download and compile source code from Fedora

Tags: fedora, compiling, download, games

There is an very old game (named "six") that is still available on Fedora as package six.x86_64 that I want to use in a hobby project of mine.  I have more recent source from the original author, but cannot compile it because I don't have tools that old (think 2010 or older -- Qt3 and such).

Fedora seems able to keep it running. Without getting their sources, I don't see how.  They list the sources at https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/six/tree/rawhide but when I try to "Fork and edit" it either stalls and times out, or once it got a little farther and had me sign up for a Fedora account (which I did) but then failed with a message about a 'method' not being allowed at that URL.  I have no idea what that means.

So I have a couple of questions:

- How do I get a copy of the source
- How does Fedora keep it working and can I do the same
- How can I compile it with modern tools

BTW the final version of the software is at the author's GitHub: https://github.com/melisgl/six and I'd encourage Fedora to switch over to that, but don't know how to contact them for that.  This is the first time I've used Fedora since around 2002, and then mostly because my school was using it.  I was into Gentoo for my own things.  Now Xubuntu.

Comment: `git clone https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/six.git`

Comment: wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/s/six-0.5.3-38.fc35.src.rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get a copy of the source

The easiest way is to download the source RPM with `dnf download --source six` (or if you are not on Fedora you can download it [from Koji](https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/six/0.5.3/38.fc35/src/six-0.5.3-38.fc35.src.rpm)). You'll get a `.src.rpm` archive which contains the upstream source tarball, patches from Fedora and the [SPEC](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#what-is-a-spec-file) file.

> How does Fedora keep it working and can I do the same

There are only two downstream patches in Fedora:

- [six-fix-DSO.patch](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/six/blob/rawhide/f/six-fix-DSO.patch) which just changes `LDFLAGS` and
- [six-gcc43.patch](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/six/blob/rawhide/f/six-gcc43.patch) that adds some includes.

So one patch that makes some small adjustment to the build process and one patch that makes the old source work with newer gcc. Nothing special.

> How can I compile it with modern tools

If you are asking how you can compile it with newer Qt, the answer is you can't. Qt3 is still [available in Fedora](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/qt3/qt3/) so the secret is having Qt3 available.

Comment: Nice.  Answer accepted. Now I just need to know how to compile -- with Qt3 is fine.